# Let a daemon simulate keypress with xdo

Tags: c, daemon, xdotool

I'm trying to make a daemon simulate a keypress. I got it already working for a non daemon process.

```
#include <xdo.h>

int main() 
{
    xdo_t * x = xdo_new(NULL);
    xdo_enter_text_window(x, CURRENTWINDOW, "Hallo xdo!", 500000);
   
    return 0;
}
```

If I try the same code for my daemon I get the following error

```
Error: Can't open display: (null)
```

Is there a way to still make it work with xdo or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Your process must know the `$DESKTOP` environment variable specifying the desktop session to send these keys to, and yours doesn't seem to have that environment set.

Which also means you must realize it needs to have all the necessary privileges, which means access to `~/.Xauthority` of the owner of the session, and the sockets in `/tmp/.X11-unix`

Answer (score -1):

I going to put this out there in case it helps someone.  I can't say that this will solve the OPs problem though.

In my crontab, I have set a visual alerter.  It failed in the beginning because it didn't know what display I was using.  But adding the following before the command I want to execute, it started working.

`export DISPLAY=:0; COMMAND_YOU_WISH_TO_RUN`